How to generate an array with specific conditions?
To randomly generate an array of 10 non-negative integers with a mean of 3 and a variance of 2.

Clear["`*"]
list = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 10]
mean = (Total@%)/10
Variance@list

How can one achieve the automatic random generation of a compliant array?

There will likely only be a handful (if any at all) possible sets of such numbers (for example, there are only 9 solutions for a set of 8 integers with $0\leq x_i\leq 8$). Why exactly do you need this, and are you sure you are asking for the right thing?

Again, you are pretending that you've made effort with some irrelevant code. (-1)

One way is to generate very many candidates of 10 random integers
candidates = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {1000000, 10}];

and then filter them using your conditions
filter = Select[EqualTo[2]@*Variance] @* Select[EqualTo[3]@*Mean]

Finally,
results = filter@candidates

You can check Mean/@results and Variance/@results gives 3 and 2, respectively.
Rather than 10^6 I checked 10^8 candidates.  I sorted the results to see how often each set shows up.
sorted = Sort[Sort /@ results];
Tally[sorted]

The result of my random trial is
{
  {{0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},  24},
  {{0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},   4},
  {{0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5}, 193},
  {{0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5},   9},
  {{1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},   4},
  {{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5}, 142},
  {{1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5}, 157},
  {{1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6},   8},
  {{1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5}, 152},
  {{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6}, 227},
  {{2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5},   3},
  {{2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6},   2},
  {{2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6},  13}
}

which gives you a stochastic estimate of the relative frequency with which these sets are generated by this procedure.  If you need a flat distribution over all possible sets you're better off enumerating them all in a pre-processing step and just using a random choice.

(I only drew integers from 0 to 10 because that's what you showed in your example.)

You can play with RandomVariate[] to achieve what you need, provided you know what shape you want for your distribution (e.g. uniform, Poisson, etc.). While playing with it a bit, I found that the SkellamDistribution[] gives what you want in a very simple manner.
This distribution accepts two integer parameters, say A and B, such that m = Mean[SkellamDistribution[A,B]] = A - B and v = Variance[SkellamDistribution[A,B]] = A + B, provided that both A and B are positive greater than 0.
In your case, you have $v=A-B=3$ and $m=A+B=2$, thus $A=(v+m)/2=5/2$ and $B=(v-m)/2=-1/2$, which means that you need to do a bit of tweaking. The important thing is to have the correct variance, since we can later achieve the desired mean by adding a constant. You can see that using $n=1$ you would have $A=(v+n)/2=3/2$ and $B=(v-n)/2=1/2$ with acceptable values for both $A$ and $B$. Now you can use
RandomVariate[SkellamDistribution[(n + v)/2, (v - n)/2], 10]

to generate your array and then add $m-n=2$ to all your values to achieve the desired distribution. For example:
Mean[RandomVariate[SkellamDistribution[(n + v)/2, (v - n)/2], 10^6] + 2]//N
Variance[RandomVariate[SkellamDistribution[(n + v)/2, (v - n)/2], 10^6] + 2]//N

result in 3.00013 and 1.9992, respectively.

You may define equations for the integers, However, take care to exclude permutations, otherwise it will run forever.
Here is an example and I use "Timing" to give an idea how long it takes:
n = 10;
var = Array[a, n];
eq = {Mean[var] == 3, StandardDeviation[var] == 2, LessEqual @@ var};
FindInstance[eq, var, NonNegativeIntegers]  // Timing

{593.406, {{a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> 1, a[4] -> 3, a[5] -> 3, 
   a[6] -> 4, a[7] -> 4, a[8] -> 5, a[9] -> 5, a[10] -> 5}}}

